# Scale-invariant geometries where $C/d \neq \pi$

Tags: geometry

Is there a geometry where everywhere, or locally: $$ \frac{C}{d} = \mathrm{constant} \neq \pi$$
$C, d$ being the circumference and diameter of a circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For example, if you equip $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the [$l_1$ metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), then a circle of diameter $d$ has circumference $4d$.

Comment: Thanks! Any other examples?

Comment: @Eelvex: with $l_\infty$, we again have $C/d=4$. The other $l_p$s all have $C/d$ constant but I haven't tried to work out what the values are.

Comment: any other examples apart from $L^p$ spaces?